# Subtract Array vs Add Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach (array_keys($R + $A) as $arrKey) {
$sums[$arrKey] = (isset($R[$arrKey]) ? $R[$arrKey] : 0) + (isset($A[$arrKey]) ? $A[$arrKey] : 0);}
```

The above works. Arrays don't need to have the same number of keys, and it adds it properly.

```
foreach (array_keys($B - $C) as $arrKey) {
$sums[$arrKey] = (isset($B[$arrKey]) ? $B[$arrKey] : 0) - (isset($C[$arrKey]) ? $C[$arrKey] : 0);}
foreach (array_keys($B + $C) as $arrKey) {
$sums[$arrKey] = (isset($B[$arrKey]) ? $B[$arrKey] : 0) - (isset($C[$arrKey]) ? $C[$arrKey] : 0);}
```

Both of the above do not work. They print out Fatal error: Unsupported operand types (and they all point to the first line in each (the lines with "foreach" in it). When I want things added, they may or may not have equal numbers. When I want things subtracted, both arrays have equal numbers.

So, my question is: why does the addition work, but not the subtraction? And how would one then subtract?

Comment: + is "merging" the arrays rather than "adding" them: array_diff() might give you an equivalent, depending on what it is you're actually expecting

Answer (score 0):

[PHP only supports `+` for arrays,](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) not `-`.

Instead, use [`array_diff($B, $C)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: But that wouldn't subtract arrays, would it? If one array contained values 10, 15, 20, and I wanted to subtract 5, 10, 15 from it, the resulting array should contain 5, 5, 5. Using array_diff, the resulting array should contain just 20 since 10 and 15 are in both arrays, and that's not what I want to do...

Comment: @WitoldKowelski oh, I had no idea from your question that that's what you wanted to do.  The `+` doesn't add each element of the array either.  Sounds like you just want to use a loop.